# Selection sort on the array $\{5,9,11,10,2\}$

Tags: algorithms, sorting, c

I want to understand how the algorithm of selection sort sorts the given array,
$$A[5]=\{5,9,11,10,2\}$$
Step -$1:-$
I compare A[0] with remaining elements of the array and since $A[4]<A[0]$ I swap them which leaves me with,
$$A=\{2,9,11,10,5\}$$
Step-$2:-$ Repeating the similar procedure for $A[1]$ gives
$$\{2,5,11,10,9
\}$$
Step-$3:-$ Repeating similar procedure gives
$$\{2,5,10,11,9\}$$
And the for loop stops. But the array isn't sorted yet. Is there any mistake with my interpretation of the algorithm?

C program for selection sort:-

```
#include <stdio.h>

void selectionSort(int arr[], int n) {
    int i, j, minIndex, temp;
    
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        minIndex = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (arr[j] < arr[minIndex]) {
                minIndex = j;
            }
        }
        if (minIndex != i) {
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[minIndex];
            arr[minIndex] = temp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should give the pseudocode of the algorithm that you are calling "selection sort" (because it is unclear with your description).

Answer (score 0):

You are stopping the `i` loop too soon.

You should try it again and keep track of the value of $i$ and keep in mind that in an array of length $n$, indices of the array are between $0$ and $n-1$.

Comment: I tried out his code and gave as an input the array that was written in the question and the C code sorted it, I don't understand why he assumes that for loop stops there. (I added i<n, instead of i<n-1, but I think i<n-1 (theoretically changes) but didn't change computation, however of course i<n should be there)

Comment: @Nathaniel,@math boy. I actually misunderstood the code and got my answer after some verification. I thank your answers and comments.

Comment: @mathboy `i < n` is unnecessary: the last loop with `i = n - 1` does nothing, because the last element is necessary the greatest.

Comment: (@Nathaniel *last element is necessary the greatest* as well as the *smallest left*, more interesting in a loop establishing this.)

Comment: @greybeard you are right, of course. My point was that the loop invariant being "Elements at indices between 0 and $i-1$ are at the right position", it was not needed to do the last loop, because the element at index $n-1$, being the greatest, is at the right position.

Comment: yeah i<n is unnecessary, last element will be greatest by all means, no importance of running loop another time.